# React & TypeScript usage of component passed via props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `Sidebar` component which passes unique icons into a `SidebarRow` child component via props.

```
import SidebarRow from './SidebarRow';
import {
    CogIcon,
    UsersIcon
} from '@heroicons/react/solid';

const Sidebar: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <div className="p-2 mt-5 max-w-5xl xl:min-w-lg">
            <SidebarRow src="" title="Tom Mc" />
            <SidebarRow Icon={UsersIcon} title="Friends" />
            <SidebarRow Icon={CogIcon} title="Account" />
        </div>    
    )
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Within the `SidebarRow` component an interface defines the incoming props. Here I am attempting to conditionally render either an image or an Icon, depending on which is passed in.

```
import React from "react";

interface SidebarRowProps {
    src?: string
    Icon?: React.FC
    title: string
};

const SidebarRow: React.FC<SidebarRowProps> = ({ src, Icon, title }) => {
    return (
        <div className="">
            {src && (
                <img className="rounded-full" src={src} alt="" width="30" height="30" />            
            )}
            {Icon && (
                <Icon className="h-8 w-8 text-blue-500" />
            )}
            <p className="hidden sm:inline-flex font-medium">{title}</p>
        </div>    
    )
};

export default SidebarRow;
```

I am receiving the below error for the `className` attribute on the `Icon` component:

```
Type '{ className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)
(JSX attribute) className: string
```

How can I define the Icon type so that the className property does not throw this error?

Thank you!

Comment: try this: `Icon?: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>`, if found in the source code of your icon library this type, className does not exists on type `React.FC`

Comment: The Sidebar component then flags an error for the elements passed to Icon via props: Value of type '(props: SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) => Element' has no properties in common with type 'SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>'. Did you mean to call it?ts(2560)
Sidebar.tsx(11, 30): Did you mean to call this expression?
(alias) function UsersIcon(props: React.ComponentProps<'svg'>): JSX.Element
import UsersIcon

Comment: Can you share your full code so I can try it ?

Comment: Thanks, here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-water-r4scl

Comment: Use `React.ComponentType` instead of `React.FC`. Example:
`Icon?: React.ComponentType<React.HtmlHTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>>`. You can change `React.HtmlHTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>` to the Props Type of your Icon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code works fine

```html
import React from "react";

interface SidebarRowProps {
    src?: string
    Icon?: React.ComponentType<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>
    title: string
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Heroicon types were changed in [2.0.17](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/heroicons/pull/966). Per [regarding the icons type signature #981](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/heroicons/discussions/981), the correct way to type icons is now one of

```
type Icon = React.FC<Parameters<typeof UsersIcon>[0]>
```

or

```
type IconSVGProps = React.PropsWithoutRef<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>> & React.RefAttributes<SVGSVGElement>
type IconProps = IconSVGProps & {
      title?: string
      titleId?: string
 }

 type Icon = React.FC<IconProps>
```